# Server 2012 Essentials Default Web Site - Safe to remove/change port

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I've recently begun setting up a new remote dedicated server for our internal applications, Previously we've run two internal servers and now we have a single server running Windows Server 2012 Essentials.

Now my issue is, that the previous webhost was a full windows server 2012, Now i use this to host web services for our applications, Unfortunately essentials already has it's own default website using port 80/443, Now i want my services to run on those ports.

I know the default website offers Remote Web Access, but i have no need or interest in that, would it be safe for me to change the port for this default site, or even turn it off completely?

I'm not 100% sure what else uses the default site, I wanted to avoid removing a service the server itself needs and my google searching isn't turning up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base server OS itself doesn't need IIS, but I just followed the configuration wizard for Essentials 2012 R2 and following the defaults, it creates several sites and applications:

[image: Server Essentials default Web Sites]

Whether you need all this, depends on how you are using the server, if you don't think you need anything, you can stop all three sites and create a new site for your own stuff on ports 80/443

There is more here than just `Remote Web Access`, the Certificate Authority web site works without Remote Web Access enabled.

If it is an internal server, I would give it a second IP and then bind your new sites to that IP, or just use hostheaders to access your sites.